# Do these sentences differ?

Tags: meaning, difference, word-choice, word-order

Is there any difference in meaning, or reason to prefer one over the other, between these two sentences?

> Es ist fast jeder größere Ort mit der Bahn zu erreichen.

> Fast jeder größere Ort erreicht mit der Bahn.

Comment: For starters, the second sentence is grammatically wrong.

Comment: Stylistically, I'd prefer "Fast jeder größere Ort ist mit der Bahn erreichbar."

Comment: To offer a correct alternative the second choice should be changed. My closest proposal is: *Fast jeden größeren Ort erreicht man mit der Bahn*.

Comment: To join the club of alternative providers, here is another one, closer to the first sentence: _Fast jeder größere Ort ist mit der Bahn zu erreichen._

Comment: Yes! These corrections answer my question completely and are very enlightening. Many thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 1):

This community wiki is intended to clear the question from the unanswered queue. In fact, it has been answered in form of comments.

1. "Fast jeder größere Ort erreicht mit der Bahn" is grammatically wrong.
2. "Es ist fast jeder größere Ort mit der Bahn zu erreichen" is correct, but stylistically "Fast jeder größere Ort ist mit der Bahn erreichbar" should be preferred.
3. Alternative formulations are

- Fast jeden größeren Ort erreicht man mit der Bahn.
- Fast jeder größere Ort ist mit der Bahn zu erreichen.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a native speaker of German, so I relied on machine translations to reveal how these differ.  This is what I discovered:

> **Es ist fast jeder größere Ort mit der Bahn zu erreichen.**

is translated by **[DeepL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DeepL_Translator)** as:

> *It is possible to reach almost every major town by train.*

Now for the other variant:

> **Fast jeder größere Ort erreicht mit der Bahn.**

Even though infinitezero states that this variant of the first example (the one seen immediately above) is not grammatically correct (and I don't doubt this), DeepL translates this as:

> *Almost every major town can be reached by train.*

If I have DeepL translate one of the suggested corrections, it gives these:

> **Fast jeder größere Ort ist mit der Bahn erreichbar.**
> *Almost every major town can be reached by train.*

> **Fast jeden größeren Ort erreicht man mit der Bahn.**
> *One can reach almost every major town by train.*

> **Fast jeder größere Ort ist mit der Bahn zu erreichen.**
> *Almost every major town can be reached by train.*

**[Google Translate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Translate)** gives the following for all five variants (with some very minor variation):

> *Almost every major town can be reached by train.*

It may be helpful to know that the word "**[erreichbar](https://www.wordreference.com/deen/erreichbar)**" is an adjective that means "**achievable**," "**attainable**," or, more colloquially, "**doable**."  The word "**[erreichen](https://www.wordreference.com/deen/erreichen)**," on the other hand, is a transitive verb that means to "**reach**," "**accomplish**," or "**achieve**."

---

*Note: I hope my answer helps in some way.  I realize you tagged this with "meaning," which would imply you aren't all that interested in the English translations, but sometimes differences in translations can reveal differences in the original language.  I don't know if the ones I provided will help all that much, but I do know that this thread will at least be of a bit more interest to those who prefer to see some English in at least one of the answers.  Nevertheless, and I hope this isn't too bold to say, I am hoping someone will provide an answer that will explain why one variant is grammatically incorrect and why one variant should be preferred over another.*